# Video capture tool: capture n frames per second

Tags: video

Is there a program that allows me to pass in a video and capture the screen at every n frames? For example maybe I want to export screenshots at 24 frames per second from point A to point B, so the program will be exporting 24 images per second. The amount of frames I would like to capture can be specified (maybe I only want 1 fps, maybe 10 fps, maybe 24, 30, 60, ..)

Preferably, it would be part of a larger program that supports various video formats. At least, it should support the more common formats out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is, specially if you're not afraid of the command line, ffmpeg can pretty much handle a variety of video related tasks you throw at it. [This](http://muzso.hu/2008/12/28/extracting-thumbnails-still-images-frames-from-a-video-with-ffmpeg) has tips on what you're trying to accomplish.
It can even be easily scriptable so you don't have to repeat the steps everytime, what OS are you using?

Comment: win7. I've used ffmpeg before to make simple videos out of a sequence of images; didn't know it had all sorts of functions available though. Guess I'll have to look at the docs some more.